# how to use print command in command prompt(Windows)

Tags: windows

I want to print the word document from dos command prompt(Windows-XP).

I have installed the printer using IP address and Standard TCP/IP port.

I am not using LPT or COM Ports,

Could some one help me out...

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/post-114567.html&sid=1d027acf414d4372134f1004c91c96c6#114567), you can use the actual word program to run macros on the file.
I did:

```
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\WINWORD.EXE" "MyFile.doc" /q /n mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit
```

And word was opened, the file was printed and the word was closed again. This of course might not be exactly what you need, but at least it does the job. Remeber that the path might be different on your system (as pointed out in the comments)

Comment: Do not hardcode the path to the executable. The Word executable may not be located at the path you hardcode. For example, the above command won't work on my system as the path to the executable is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE` on my machine, and that was the default installation path.