# Printing a MS Word file from cmd

Tags: cmd, ms-word, command-line-interface

Is there any way to print a `.doc` or `.rtf` file from the Windows command line silently?
I am working on a receipt printing application and I would like to perform a silent automatic print using a `cmd` command.

Comment: "shell" tag is commonly associated with UNIX-like systems, but Word with Windows. Please clarify which environment you are referring to. EDIT: assuming Windows, because of `cmd`. Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357523/how-to-use-print-command-in-command-promptwindows answer your question?

Comment: with linux, have you tried to work with `lp` command (see CUPS)

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity, but i am on windows environment. and i need the print job to be silent. Is there any way to do that? The link provided above doesn't allow silent printing as it opens msword before hand. Also i tried wordpad's print command and it also opens itself for a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpad can open rtf, doc and docx files, so you don't even need word. Then you can use wordpad's command line switch to print to the default printer.  `start wordpad.exe /p "path\filename.ext"`

Comment: Yes, it works. Then again, it is not exactly "silent printing" cause wordpad opens itself for a fraction of a second and then closes again. I would like to perform the printing without any such pop up if that's possible.

Comment: You're right, it's not completely silent. I don't think you'll get that from a command prompt. Even if you go down the vbs path like http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/scripts/msoffice/word/#OPWD.htm you will get a flash of word document sometimes. Even if you add: objWord.Application.Visible = false it still flashes up. I think your only true cmd line option would be a 3rd party utility like 2Printer - just search for silent command line print utility. Alternatively, if you are developing the application you can often do silent prints in code (depending on language).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am actually doing the program in java, but i couldn't find any effective method of printing .rtf files from java's printing libraries. That's why i opted for command line printing options in the first place.

Comment: This may help... but I'm no java developer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522735/print-multiple-rtf-files-in-java

Comment: start /MIN   -- reduces the visual noise

Answer (score -1):

Shell is an accepted Windows terminolgy and refers to the graphical user interface. It is known as *The Windows Shell*. And it can do what you want.

```
Set xlBook = GetObject("C:\Users\David Candy\Documents\Super.xls")
For each wsheet in xlbook.worksheets
    wsheet.printOut 
next
```

At its most basic.

This is VBS using COM.

The malcontents strike